# Rails session variable works for a while, then suddenly stops working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox

**Update**
Confirmed to be a timing issue on the server. Answer posted.

**Description**
I have a Rails application that has been running without problems for months, but suddenly I cannot login. When this happens, it occurs simultaneously both for the container based app and for the local developer version running natively. Both installations run on the same Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox. A server restart will make things work again for a while. It worked when I left office yesterday, but today it does not work. I am the only user of these locally installed apps. Its for development. Users of the app has not seen this issue, but I want to make sure that this does not happen to them.

**versions**

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- VirtualBox 7.0.12
- Rails 6.1.7.6

**session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 1.hour
```

I store and retrive with `session[:user_id]`

**Observations**

- session controller: logs clearly states that the session is stored and that the variable :user_id can be retriveved. session.id shows the object id. When the session_controller has finished - everything is at normal.
- when I redirect to the home page, the session info is gone. There is no variable, and even the session.id is nil.
- changing code base to earlier versions have no effect
- when the problem arise in a container based app, the same problem also appears in the rails native application.
- When i restart the linux server, I can login again. but after a while the problem reappears.
- Restart of the linux native rails server has no effect.
- docker-compose down and up has no effect.
- I have tried to clear cookies in the browser, but it has no effect
- Changing browsers have no effect
- I can run all Rails test without problems, and they involve a lot of logins... both system tests and controller tests.

**changes recently**

- upgraded from windows 10 to windows 11. hyper-v was automatically installed, but I removed it, to avoid VirtualBox being emulated.
- I upgraded VirtualBox from 6.x to 7.x
- Upgraded to Rails 6.1.7.6 some weeks ago + a bundle update. But when this problem strikes, I can roll back to any version, and it makes no difference.

**possibly related**

- I edited some files directly in the container to troubleshoot and insert some puts statements. A restart would pick up the edits. I could do this 3-4 times, but suddenly the container cannot see new edits any more, even after restart. Weird.

To me it looks like this is a non-app issue. Corrupt server?
Anythings else to try - to zoom in on the actual cause? thx.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a timing issue on the Ubuntu server.

**Fix server date/time**

```
service ntp start
```

I did some tests to confirm, and set a time in the past. Login would start to fail again. I tested on future dates, many days ahead of today. This would actually work. So it seem to fail only if the server time lags behind the current time, possibly the time of the browser accessing the server.

- I will need to monitor this service, because it seems to stop from time to time.
- I will also try to compare server time with the browser time, and present an error in the log/user interface, telling the time is wrong - or even fix it. This way the proper solution can be found much quicker.